# An empty pipe element is not allowed, Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell (v5) but found on the web a way to list all non empty logs e.g. in the last 30 minutes.
However, I cannot redirect the output to a file.
Any suggestions gratefully received.

```
$time1 = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 30
$logs = Get-WinEvent -ListLog * | Where-Object {$_.RecordCount} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty LogName
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName=$logs; Level=1,2,3; StartTime=(Get-Date)-$time1}
| out-file c:\temp\test1.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to make PowerShell look for the continuation of a pipeline on the *next line*:

- Place `|` at the *end* of a line.

  - More generally: any statement that *invariably* needs more tokens to be syntactically valid causes PowerShell to keep parsing on the next line.
  - *Update*: In PowerShell [Core] v7+ you may alternative place the `|` at the start of the (very) *next* line.
- Use an *explicit line continuation* by placing `` ` `` (PowerShell's escape character) at the *very end* of a line (not even whitespace is allowed after).

---

**What you tried:**

**Update**: As implied above, **your command now *does* work in *PowerShell [Core] v7+***.
The following explanation therefore applies only to PowerShell 6.x and below, including Windows PowerShell.

PowerShell reads the following as *two* statements:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName=$logs; Level=1,2,3; StartTime=(Get-Date)-$time1}
| out-file c:\temp\test1.txt
```

The `Get-WinEvent` line is syntactically complete by itself, so PowerShell considers it its own statement.

Thus, to PowerShell, the next statement *starts with* `|`, which prompts the error message you saw (there must be a command or expression before a statement's first `|`).